# How regular expressions stop matching

Tags: regex, regex-greedy

```
aws-sdk-java/1.9.4 Linux/3.10.0-862.mt20190308.130.el7.x86_64 Java_HotSpot(TM)_64-Bit_Server_VM/25.45-b02/1.8.0_45
```

I want to get substr 'aws-sdk-java/1.9.4'

Here is my regular

```
(\S+?\/\S+?)(\s|$)
```

but it matches many times
[image: result]

is someone can help me? Thank you very much~

Comment: Maybe anchor it at the start? `^\S+\/\S+` (or a bit more efficient `^[^\s\/]+\/\S+`)? Please share your current code you are using to retrieve matches.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Your idea is right，thanks.Here is my code (^\S+?\/\S+?)(\s|$)

Answer (score 1):

You could make the pattern a bit more specific, and get a match only without capture groups.

```
(?<!\S)\w+(?:-\w+)*\/\d+(?:\.\w+)*(?!\S)
```

**Explanation**

- `(?<!\S)` Assert a whitespace boundary to the left
- `\w+(?:-\w+)*` Match 1+ word chars and optionally repeat `-` and 1+ word chars
- `\/` Match `/` (Depending on the delimiter of the pattern, you don't have to escape the `/`)
- `\d+(?:\.\w+)*` Match 1+ digits and optionally repeat `.` and 1+ word characters
- `(?!\S)` Assert a whitespace boundary to the right

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/CCV7Oy/1)

Or a boader variant:

```
(?<!\S)[^\/\s]+\/\w+(?:\.\w+)*(?!\S)
```

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/4PfTFq/1)

Comment: this is very helpful , thanks. But it can't match end with non space. Just like  'aws-sdk-go/0.9.4rc5'

Comment: @xf Like this? `(?<!\S)\w+(?:-\w+)*\/\d+(?:\.\d+)*\w*(?!\S)` https://regex101.com/r/QSOk0i/1

Comment: @xf Or shorter `^\w+(?:-\w+)*\/\d+(?:\.\w+)*(?!\S)` https://regex101.com/r/4Ms0KY/1